# Creating different power methods

Tags: java

I had some code that calculates powers, by calling square, cube and hypercube methods. Currently the cube method calls the square method in the program, and then the hypercube method calls the cube method. I want to replace the calls to cube and hypercube with calls to the power method, but I'm completely stuck.

Here's the original code which worked.

```
  public int square( int x ){
    int i = ( x*x );
    return i;
}
public int cube( int x ){
    int i = (x * square(x) );
    return i;
}
public int hypercube( int x ){
    int i = (x * cube(x) );
    return i;
}

public int power(int x, int n){  
    int k;
    if (n==2){
        k = square(x);
    }
    else if (n==3){
        k = cube(x);
    }
    else if (n==4){
        k = hypercube(x);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        k = x;
    }
    else {
        k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            k *= x;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Now like I said I want to replace the calls in the cube and hypercube methods with calls to the power method, then I still have calls to square, cube etc in the power method. So I want to remove calls to these methods entirely since I no longer need them. Its really bugging me.
This is what I have so far but its giving me StackOverFlowError.

```
 public int square( int x, int n ){
    int i = power( x, n );
    return i;
}
public int cube( int x, int n ){
    int i = power(x , n );
    return i;
}
public int hypercube( int x, int n ){
    int i = power(x , n );
    return i;
}

public int power(int x, int n){  
    int k;
    if (n==2){
        k = square(x, n);
    }
    else if (n==3){
        k = cube(x, n);
    }
    else if (n==4){
        k = hypercube(x, n);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        k = x;
    }
    else {
        k = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            k *= x;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: I can see clearly that I'm going about it the complete wrong way and I can see why it won't work. I'm just confused as to how I can make it work

Comment: YOu already have answer given to this in your previous question. Look for answer given by `@ MightyPork`

Answer (score 0):

First off, as you've recognized this is a very bad way of going about things. So anybody else reading this, apart from the usual call to avoid reinventing the wheel (unless it's for educational purposes) **don't implement your exponentiation methods this way!**

That being said, the reason you're getting a stack overflow (so appropriate) is that you have a circular definition. The simplest way to see this is trying to track down how `power` works by hand. Let's say I want to run `power(3, 2)`. What happens? Well `power(3, 2)` recognizes this as an instance of `n == 2` and so goes to the `square` method. However, the `square` method relies on the `power` method to get things done and then you repeat ad infinitum. Hence you get function calls piling up on your stack until you run out of space.

P.S. Incidentally, if you are looking at implementing integer exponentiation for personal edification, you might want to look into repeated squaring. It makes your code much faster (a logarithmic number of multiplication operations as opposed to a linear number).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that there is an infinite cycle going on here.
If n=2, then power calls sqaure which in turn calls power and n doesn't change either.

You get StackOverFlowError usually when you deal with infinities.

power(x,n) must be independent of cube or square if you want to get rid of those.